# FullText Index does not work even after I created them

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

Here is the error I get:

```
Message: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]
Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view 'database.dbo.crm_main' 
because it is not full-text indexed.
```

But I already created them, here is the command I used:

```
use [database]
create fulltext catalog FullTextCatalog as default
create fulltext index on [database].[dbo].[crm_main] key index PK_crm_main 
ON FullTextCatalog WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO
```

No error was encountered during the creation process.  What I am doing wrong?

Here is my sql statement:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 *
FROM [database].[dbo].[crm_main]   
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE ([database].[dbo].[crm_main], *, '%Wade%') 
AS SEARCH_TABLE ON SEARCH_TABLE.[KEY] = crm_main.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only mistake you have made is you did not mention the Column names
>   in your Create index statement that on which columns you want to
>   create indexes see below.

```
create fulltext index 
ON [dbo].[crm_main](Column1,Column2) --<-- you need to mention the column names
key index PK_ID                        -- on which you want to create FT indexes                                
ON FullTextCatalog 
WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO;
```

Comment: What if I want full index on the whole table?

Comment: @YongkeBillYu then you will need to mention all the columns, but before you do that make sure datatypes of all the columns does allow you to create FT Indexes on them. there are some limitation. Read here the section for `TYPE COLUMN` http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx